# How would you handle queries in CQRS?

Tags: database, command, microservices, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am in the process of learning Microservices and I'm learning to implement them using popular Domain Driven Design tactical patterns and CQRS. For my first project I'm trying to create a simple ECommerce setup because every tutorial regarding the subject seem to be Ecommerce tutorial.

I am not using Event Sourcing at this point in time, just SQL databases without events.

After thinking about the domain for a while, I came to the conclusion of having two microservices(of many others) where one handles the usecases of Sellers, like endpoints for Adding Products to their listing, updating their information, etc., and another microservice to handle queries for products through the storefront by customers with endpoints to Get Products with different sorting and filtering options.

Now the flow that I have in mind is

1. The Seller who is already verfied and registered will add a product through the SellerWhateverService, its gets added to its database.
2. The ProductAddedIntegrationEvent will be passed through the EventBus and received by the Catalog Service.
3. The Catalog has an SaveProductOnProductAddedIntegrationEventHandler that creates a product in its own database.

I'm under the assumption that Catalog Service will be Query based service, and it should not need to have any commands since there's not going to be much business logic handling here (I'm under the assumption that commands are how the user of the API sends requests to Domain to do something).

But I'm not fully sure if I'm committed to that line of thinking or if its the right approach, and I'm wondering whether I should be using Commands -> Domain Layer -> Repositories flow here to save the products to its database, or just do direct SQL commands to save them from the IntegrationEventHandler, or if there's a better approach.
Should saving stuff in Query focused Microservices just be simple saving to database, instead of a complex flow using Commands and whatnot?

Another thing I see is its nice to have MaterializedViews of queryable data in its own database, so that Domain Objects can be modelled without worrying about how query results would look like and what data a Query would need, they can also can span data from multiple services and they could be stored in a way to improve performance.

I'm under the assumption that these Queries are going to be in their own microservices with its own database attached to it. And simple Queries that use data similar to domain objects are just part of the same Microservice but the Microservice should have a clear separation between Queries and commands. Is this line of thinking correct or am I making a mistake somewhere?

I Would love to get your point of views on these so that I can actually commit to a way of thinking without doubting myself, learning these are really overwhelming to be honest :).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no rules about what a microservice should do. The definition of a microservice indicates how it does what it does, what is its boundary, how it interacts with other services etc.

Sometimes online shopping product browsing scenarios get more important because of the performance and complexity of the queries. To manage the condition, you separate these scenarios in an independent boundary called microservice. To do that, we create an independent data store and design a performant structure to store the data.

CQRS comes in and suggests that we separate the write model of our bounded context from the read model. In that sense, we will have two microservices of the same bounded context. One of them is for browsing scenarios and the other is for handling commands that change the data.

> Microservice should have a clear separation between Queries and
> commands.

In this sentence, I think it is better to change "Microservice" to "Bounded context". A bounded context can have two microservices to handle its commands and queries (and a microservice might include two bounded contexts in general, no limits here). I think you have a bounded context named "CatalogueBoundedContext" and two microservices named "CatalogueManagement" and CatalogueBrowsing" (names might not be accurate, they just draw you a picture).

> whether I should be using Commands -> Domain Layer -> Repositories
> flow here to save the products to its database,

On the query side, you can apply any application architecture you want, but remember the business invariants checking, validations and processing already happened on the write model. So you won't have to worry about them. All you have to worry about is how to apply the write model output messages on your read model (usually a CRUD base operation would be enough).

Comment: I was thinking of Catalog Product Management as a separate Microservice called Seller Product Management and it was a bounded context, and catalog was another bounded context. I was confused if I should be validating info when creating a product in catalog after receiving ProductCreatedEvent even though validations would have happened in seller product management service. So from what you said I think I dont need to even though it's cross bounded context? Just verifying if I understood :)

Comment: @YaminNather the general rule is what does the microservice boundary tell you about the business rules or requirements? What are the requirements that your microservice wants to answer? If it's just the query performance requirements, no duplicate business invariants are needed. If it needs invariants other than your write model invariants, it seems it has other meanings for itself than the write model, and it may not be in the same bounded context as the write model.